# Duda setInterval()

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Estoy empezando con Javascript. Me he encontrado con el siguiente problema, pero no logro sacarlo:

Abrir nueva ventana desde la esquina superior izquierda hasta completar la pantalla.

Esto me abre la ventana en la posición superior izquierda, pero no sé lo de "hasta completar la pantalla":

```
    var myWindowURL = "https://www.google.es", myWindowName = "ONE";
    var myWindowProperties  = "width=600,height=400,top=0,left=0,menubar=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,statusbar=no";
    var openWindow;

    setTimeout(function() {
        openWindow = window.open(myWindowURL, myWindowName, myWindowProperties); 
    }, 0);
```

Me han dicho que se hace con setInterval() pero los ejemplos que encuentro no son para abrir ventanas :/

Comment: Por lo que leo, quieres abrir una ventana con una especie de animación, mi pregunta es, para que? Aquí te enfrentas con un problema de BOM y no de DOM, hay cosas que es mejor no tocar.

Answer (score 0):

> Me han dicho que se hace con setInterval() pero los ejemplos que
> encuentro no son para abrir ventanas

Es correcto. `setInterval()` se usa para ejecutar una función de forma repetida cada cierto tiempo. No para abrir ventanas.

En tu código la ventana debe abrirse antes y dentro de `setInterval()` debe ir el código que irá actualizando el tamaño de la ventana para dar un efecto de animación.

**NOTA:** El código en la función `setInterval()` es solo un ejemplo.

```
<script>
  var myWindowURL = "https://www.google.es", myWindowName = "ONE";
    var myWindowProperties  = "width=600,height=400,top=0,left=0,menubar=no,toolbar=no,titlebar=no,statusbar=no";
    var openWindow;

    openWindow = window.open(myWindowURL, myWindowName, myWindowProperties); 

    setInterval(function() {
        
        openWindow.resizeTo(openWindow.innerWidth + 1, openWindow.innerHeight);

    }, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: Millones de gracias, justo lo que necesitaba!